# Dynamic array in Fortran 77

Tags: arrays, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, fortran77, dynamic-allocation

I have to write a subroutine in Fortran 77(i'm using Intel Fortran), which reads the measured values from a text file and stores them in a matrix.

Since the number of measured values is always variable, I must dynamically allocate the matrix.

I know that the dynamic allocation is only possible from Fortran 90, but at that time people had the same problems, so it is also possible.
How would you proceed?

I do not want to reserve too much space for the matrix because the method is impractical for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834985/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-fortran77

Comment: Don't write Fortran 77 in year 2016, especially when you need dynamic memory allocation, it is simply not worth it. If you can't use the old Fortran 90 then allocate the stuff in C and pass it to the Fortran subroutines.

Comment: There are reasons why to use FORTRAN 77 in legacy systems. There is no reason to use FORTRAN 77 when you use Intel Fortran.

Comment: Hello Vladimir,

Unfortunately, I am forced to write in Fortran 77 because the software that I am expanding is  implemented in Fortran 77 .

Best Regards

Comment: Unless I mix Fortran 77 and Fortran 90. So I create a subroutine in f90 where I reserve the memory and run the subroutine of f77. The Intel compiler is supposed to do well.
I report later if it worked.
Or. Are there any objections?

Comment: Of course you can mix Fortran 77 and 90!!! Actually, no mixing is necessary, Most of Fortran 77 is valid Fortran 90 at the same time, mybe even Fortran 2008. Most likely your Intel Fortran translates the code as Fortran 95 and not 77, you just didn't notice it.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really are restricted to Fortran 77, you do not do dynamic allocation.  Instead, declare an array that is larger than what you think you will likely need, without it being too large to prevent the program from running on your target system.  Then store your values in that large array, separately keeping track of how many elements of the large array that you use.  If your choice of array size was not large enough, let the user know and terminate the program.

People found the lack of dynamic allocation in Fortran 77 very restrictive, so they often resorted to using non-standard language extensions.  If you decide to go down the path of language extensions, then these days the best extension to Fortran 77 to use in this situation is the allocatable array feature introduced with Fortran 90.  I think it is fair to say that all actively maintained compilers that can handle Fortran 77 will also handle Fortran 90 allocatable arrays (and then some).

Comment: Thanks IanH. I've already thought it was easier to statically allocate. I'll try both ways, but tilt to the static.

Answer (score 0):

As many people have pointed out, you don't have to stick to Fortran77, even if much of what is already written is Fortran77 compatible. Even the few features that have been deleted in Fortran 95 [See Wikipedia for a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Obsolescence_and_deletions), your compiler will probably still work fine, as long as you don't switch from Fixed Form to Free Form in the same file.

Pre-F90, what people would probably do is to declare arrays that are (hoped to be) big enough for any use case, then only use the first elements of that array.

One thing that I am not certain about, but which might be useful, is the change of scope. Short example:

```
      subroutine main(n)
          implicit none
          integer n
          integer a(n)
          print*, "Please enter the ", n, " numbers"
          read*, a
          print*, "Sum is ", sum(a)
      end subroutine main

      program dynamic
          implicit none
          integer n
          print*, "Enter size of array:"
          read*, n
          call main(n)
      end program dynamic
```

<del>I'm curious to know whether this would be Fortran77 compliant. I honestly don't know.</del> @francescalus has convinced me that it isn't.

Comment: For your final paragraph: it isn't F77.

Comment: I get mixed messages. Oracle seems to think that adjustable local arrays are F77 compliant: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007367199/index.html whereas other resources claim that adjustable arrays can only be dummy arguments, not local arrays, e.g. here: https://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/procedure.html

Comment: In the Oracle documentation note the "local array@".  That "@" denotes a non-standard extension.

Comment: Why should you care about standard? ifort has all the DEC extensions and CRAY, so you paid the $2500 for something that many people needed between 77 and 90. If you actually needed to 'roll back' the clock, then you could always make it gf77 compliant. But then that brings up the question of how to compile it. There is no separate ifort(77) nor gfortran(77),... So you can sprinkle in RESHAPES and ALLOCATES and it just compiles on either compiler.