# Vectorization of Linked-list in Fortran

Tags: linked-list, fortran, vectorization, fortran90, intel-fortran

I have millions of data points which each go through the same mathematical operations, and they do not depend on each other. Hence, this problem should in theory be vectorizable.

Now these data points would most conveniently be stored as a linked-list in Fortran so delete/add is straight-forward. The main loop would then be something like

```
do while(associated(data_points)) 

     data_points => data_points% next
       ......
enddo
```

How does this work with vectorization?

Another option would be to store all variables in an organised declared type and allocate an array of that type equal to the number of data points, something like:

```
type(type_data_points) :: data_points(1:no_data_types)
```

and then the do-loop would just be

```
do i = 1, no_data_types 
    data_points(i)% x = (...) 
    data_points(i)% y = (...) 
     ....
enddo
```

Would even the latter be vectorized  - and what options do I have beside defining each variable (`x,y, ...`) as arrays of `no_data_points` and carry out the calculations.

Comment: This question is pretty broad, but *generally* the simpler and more well-defined the memory layout is, the easier it will be. Why not a 2D array? That would be my preferred solution. Ultimately, if you really care, you must implement several methods and test.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am just trying to explore for any options with this linkedlist code style while maintaining the vectorization. The problem with array, is that my simulation is dynamic so, depending on the cases, I my might have to deallocate and allocate again to enlarge the array - so thought that the suggested way might be more elegant and would avoid all the copying when allocating and deallocating.

Comment: How frequent is the allocation/deallocation? You will likely have to do some testing. There is a lot of literature available for these sorts of implementation questions - for example I am familiar with this question for Adaptive Mesh Refinement in CFD. One paper I know is https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2014-3080

Comment: Thanks for the paper !
It depends from case to case - I do have an initial large allocation to try to incorporate for that. But even so the memory demand can be quite extensive since many data points would eventually die out and knew would be introduced. With the array approach it is not straight forward to just  add/delete those.

Comment: Testing it can be simple, as one can just at the vectorisation report to see if it vectorises. (Assuming -vec-report3 and ifort). There are also tricks like UNION /MAP, or some other way to work the data continuously... but a linked list sort of implies hopping around like Qbert.

Comment: Thinking out loud here, if the computation of each node is independent and could run async, but assuming node linkage is important to code logic, I'd still have a linked derived type, but I'd lay them out in a dynamic, contiguous array, to facilitate vectorized operations. If insertion/deletion is not that frequent, I'd run some logic to keep filling/freeing nodes until more space is needed, then I'd stretch my array by 1.5x or 2x and `move_alloc` to new contiguous storage.

Comment: If there is an underlying list that is contiguous then the could be operated on, but the do while implied hopping around. PACK could be used for the operations, or a MASK, but one need to unpack back to the right area in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what you've already mentioned in the question, the following options can be considered:

1. `deallocate` and `allocate` an array every time a datapoint is added or deleted.
2. Declaring an array which is much larger than the expected data and track how many datapoints have been added. Then you can perform the math on the sliced array itself. This is expected to give very good performance. If you hit a point where you need a larger array, you may have to `deallocate` and `allocate` the array again. This requires fewer allocations than before thus is a cleaner option.
3. A non-standard language extension as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497329/4782513).

The linked list data structure you have is also ok but due considerations is to be made when parallelising with `MPI`. Communication with arrays is far more efficient and also convenient. Since the data is independent and you intend to perform operations independently I presume you also need all data gathered again. In the linked list case, you may have to first collect all data to communicate in a buffer and then send/receive/allgather. However, if it is already structured in an array this is far more easier.